# $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} (1 - \frac{1}{k}) x_k$ is bounded for $x=(x_k) \in \ell_1$ and find its norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

The question is as follows:

Prove that the functional $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} (1 - \frac{1}{k}) x_k$ is linear bounded for $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \ell_1$ and find its norm.

$\textbf{Some effort:}$

First we note that $f:\ell_1 \to \mathbb{R}$. So we can use  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and so we have

\begin{align}
|f(x)| &= \left|\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right) x_k\right|\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left|\left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)x_k\right|\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left|1 - \frac{1}{k}\right| |x_k|\\
&\le \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)\right\|_{\infty} \|x\|_1\\
&= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)\right\|_{\infty}\|x\|_1
\end{align}

So $f$ is bounded and $\|f\| \leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)\right| $

Please let me know if my calculation is not correct?

And please let me know that how can I find its norm?

Thanks!

Comment: I made a few formatting edits to your question. The inequality you call Cauchy-Schwarz is not correct but I left it as it were. Also, I fixed what it seemed to me a typo in the supremum. It is not correct anyway, but it makes more sense now.

Comment: @mechanodroid Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots ) \in \ell^1$ we have:

$$|f(x)| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k} x_k\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \underbrace{\frac{k-1}{k}}_{\le 1} |x_k| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k| = \|x\|_1$$

so $f$ is bounded and $\|f\| \le 1$.

Now consider $e_n \in \ell^1$, the $n$-th canonical vector. We have:

$$\|f\| \ge \frac{|f(e_n)|}{\|e_n\|_1} = \frac{\frac{n-1}{n}}{1} = \frac{n-1}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$$

So $\|f\| \ge 1$. We conclude $\|f\| = 1$.

Comment: Many thanks! Very clever and complete answer!